# Change language layout in screen lock

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-layout, lock-screen

I'm Xubuntu 14.04.2 user. I have two keyboard layouts: Russian and English. Sometimes when I close my laptop and then go back and try to continue to work, Xubuntu wants me to enter my user password (my password consist of English letters and numbers).

*However, often my keyboard layout was set to Russian and switching keyboards doesn't work.*

I need restart my laptop to fix it.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Which is your default keyboard? Russian?  If yes, use Cyrillic characters for your password...

Comment: Thanks for a comment, but keyboard layout don't always is Russian...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the exact same problem as you and I get around by doing this:

- get rid of `gnome-screensaver` by:

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge gnome-screensaver
  ```
- Install the X screensaver by:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install xscreensaver xscreensaver-data xscreensaver-gl
  ```

Whenever you forgot to switch back to English before the system locks itself, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> log in as your admin user and `kill -9 xscreensaver` and you're back in!

(It's just a workaround and not a real "solution" but it works for me and is definitely better then shutting down and restarting)

Comment: this solution somehow messed my graphics-card configuration. reversing to prev state solved it.

Comment: @ozma sorry to hear that. Above is in no way related to graphics card subsystem so shouldn't have had any effect. Good to hear you solved it though... ;)

Comment: Thanks @Fabby. I believe it is more a greeter issue rather than graphics (lightdm, sddm etc.). Anyway, I've upgraded to 16.04 and this greater issue  has gone.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running Ubuntu 21.04 and the "dbus-monitor" solution didn't work for me, So I'm sharing the way I approached it.
using `xscreensaver-command` we can monitor status changes of the screensaver.
Then when the status change to `LOCK`, we can change the layout to `us` and change it back once the screensaver "release" the desktop

Once I had the script, I set it to run during login.

```bsh
xscreensaver-command --watch | 
  while read MSG; do
    CMD=`echo $MSG | awk '{print $1}'`
    if [[ "$CMD" == "LOCK" ]]; then
        ##### CURRENTL=$(setxkbmap -query | grep layout | awk '{print $2}')
        echo "Locked with current layout ${CURRENTL}"
        setxkbmap us
    fi

    if [[ "$CMD" == "UNBLANK" ]]; then
        ##### setxkbmap $CURRENTL
        setxkbmap us,il,us
        echo -n "Returning to "
        setxkbmap -query | grep layout | awk '{ print $2 }'
    fi
    # echo $CMD
  done
```

Comment: it works like a charm! I changed the line `setxkbmap us,il,us` to `setxkbmap us` since I don't mind changing the keyboard layout to another language after logging in from the lock screen. It hardly takes a moment.

Answer (score 1):

[Edit] This might be a workaround but right now its messing with other layout switching keybindings

[Original]
This one worked for me BUT I couldn't run it on startup and keep it running in background.

Listen to lock signal and change layout to the one of your password. (ugly workaround but seem to work)

```
dbus-monitor --session "type=signal,interface=org.gnome.ScreenSaver" | 
  while read MSG; do
    LOCK_STAT=`echo $MSG | grep boolean | awk '{print $2}'`
    if [[ "$LOCK_STAT" == "true" ]]; then
        setxkbmap us
    else
        setxkbmap -option grp:switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll us,il
    fi
  done
```

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 16.04 use another interface name:

```
dbus-monitor --session "type=signal,interface=com.canonical.Unity.Session" | 
  while read MSG; do
    LOCK_STAT=`echo $MSG | egrep -o member='.*' | cut -d '=' -f 2`
    if [[ "$LOCK_STAT" == "Locked" ]]; then
        CURRENTL=$(setxkbmap -query | grep layout | awk '{print $2}')
        echo "Locked with current layout ${CURRENTL}"
        setxkbmap us
    fi
    if [[ "$LOCK_STAT" == "Unlocked" ]]; then
        setxkbmap $CURRENTL
        echo -n "Returning to"
        setxkbmap -query | grep layout
    fi
  done
```

Answer (score 0):

xscreensaver is great but the maintainer, JWZ, has made clear that he has no intention of supporting multiple keyboards.

xsecurelock is a better solution.  It supports switch keyboard layouts from within the screen saver and will also give you a bold red notice if caps lock is on.  It doesn't have a built-in timer like xscreensaver does so you'll need to follow the instructions on their webpage to get it to run automatically after a timeout.

Comment: how to make `xsecurelock` as the default locker?

Comment: how can I switch keyboard layouts in `xsecurelock`?

Answer (score 0):

I just improved the previous examples for Ubuntu 20.04

```bsh
dbus-monitor --session "type=signal,interface=org.gnome.ScreenSaver" | 
  while read MSG; do
    LOCK_STAT=`echo $MSG | grep boolean | awk '{print $2}'`
    if [[ "$LOCK_STAT" == "true" ]]; then
        CURRENTL=$(setxkbmap -query | grep layout | awk '{print $2}')
        echo "Locked with current layout ${CURRENTL}"
        setxkbmap us
    fi

    if [[ "$LOCK_STAT" == "false" ]]; then
        setxkbmap $CURRENTL
        echo -n "Returning to "
        setxkbmap -query | grep layout | awk '{ print $2 }'
    fi
  done
```