# Why does light-locker keep the screen black after unlock?

Tags: xubuntu, lightdm, lock-screen, light-locker

A Xubuntu 16.04 fully patched machine with a freshly created user wont let me unlock after using light-locker to lock my screen (regardless if lock was activated manually or via timeout).
The **screen remains black** (but powered) on correct password entry

Killing light-locker from tty1 will reveal the desktop then (and consequently prevents further locking).

**Steps attempted:**

- enabled/disabled lock in light-locker settings & in power settings (no change)
- used xscreensaver instead of light-locker (works)
- tested if issue is related to suspend or closing lid (it is not)

  - however, after suspend the black screen reveals the `This session is locked: You will be redirected to the unlock dialog automatically in a few seconds` message - without any redirection taking place
- purged+reinstalled lightdm, light-locker and xubuntu-default-settings
- using `loginctl unlock-session` has no effect
- `systemctl status lightdm` only reveals (harmless, expected) messages about kwallet pam module missing
- examined dpkg log for upgrades between "it worked" and "it doesn't work any more" (none suspicious) and booted previous kernel (issue persists)
- Compared behaviour between session-initiated light-locker and manually started one (no difference)
- added user to group `nopasswdlogin` group (black screen then occurs right after locking, not only after entering password)

**What additional steps could prove useful in figuring out how to fix this?**

Debugging log:

```
$ export LC_ALL=C; light-locker --debug & ( sleep 5; echo "## Locking now"; light-locker-command --lock; sleep 10; echo "### 10 seconds have passed - entering password now"; sleep 10; echo "### 10 more seconds have passwd - Killing"; killall light-locker; sleep 5; echo "### Killed now" )  
[1] 23463
[gs_debug_init] gs-debug.c:106 (00:08:32):   Debugging enabled
[main] light-locker.c:142 (00:08:32):    initializing light-locker 1.7.0
[main] light-locker.c:144 (00:08:32):    lock after screensaver 10
[main] light-locker.c:145 (00:08:32):    late locking 0
[main] light-locker.c:146 (00:08:32):    lock on suspend 1
[main] light-locker.c:147 (00:08:32):    lock on lid 0
[main] light-locker.c:148 (00:08:32):    idle hint 1
[query_session_id] gs-listener-dbus.c:2088 (00:08:32):   org.freedesktop.login1.NoSessionForPID raised:
 PID 23463 does not belong to any known session


[init_session_id] gs-listener-dbus.c:2180 (00:08:32):    Got session-id: (null)
[query_sd_session_id] gs-listener-dbus.c:2164 (00:08:32):    Couldn't determine our own sd session id: No such process
[init_session_id] gs-listener-dbus.c:2185 (00:08:32):    Got sd-session-id: (null)
[init_seat_path] gs-listener-dbus.c:2262 (00:08:32):     Got seat: /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
[gs_listener_delay_suspend] gs-listener-dbus.c:449 (00:08:32):   Delay suspend
[gs_listener_x11_acquire] gs-listener-x11.c:172 (00:08:32):  ScreenSaver Registered
[listener_dbus_handle_system_message] gs-listener-dbus.c:1330 (00:08:32):    obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameAcquired destination=:1.316
## Locking now
[gs_grab_grab_root] gs-grab-x11.c:647 (00:08:37):    Grabbing the root window
[gs_grab_get_keyboard] gs-grab-x11.c:153 (00:08:37):     Grabbing keyboard widget=E3
[gs_grab_get_mouse] gs-grab-x11.c:213 (00:08:37):    Grabbing mouse widget=E3
[gs_manager_create_windows_for_screen] gs-manager.c:548 (00:08:37):  Creating 1 windows for screen 0
[gs_manager_create_window_for_monitor] gs-manager.c:324 (00:08:37):  Creating window for monitor 0 [0,0] (1600x900)
[update_geometry] gs-window-x11.c:197 (00:08:37):    got geometry for monitor 0: x=0 y=0 w=1600 h=900
[update_geometry] gs-window-x11.c:210 (00:08:37):    using geometry for monitor 0: x=0 y=0 w=1600 h=900
[update_geometry] gs-window-x11.c:197 (00:08:37):    got geometry for monitor 0: x=0 y=0 w=1600 h=900
[update_geometry] gs-window-x11.c:210 (00:08:37):    using geometry for monitor 0: x=0 y=0 w=1600 h=900
[gs_window_move_resize_window] gs-window-x11.c:243 (00:08:37):   Move and/or resize window on monitor 0: x=0 y=0 w=1600 h=900
[update_geometry] gs-window-x11.c:197 (00:08:37):    got geometry for monitor 0: x=0 y=0 w=1600 h=900
[update_geometry] gs-window-x11.c:210 (00:08:37):    using geometry for monitor 0: x=0 y=0 w=1600 h=900
[gs_window_move_resize_window] gs-window-x11.c:243 (00:08:37):   Move and/or resize window on monitor 0: x=0 y=0 w=1600 h=900
[update_geometry] gs-window-x11.c:197 (00:08:37):    got geometry for monitor 0: x=0 y=0 w=1600 h=900
[update_geometry] gs-window-x11.c:210 (00:08:37):    using geometry for monitor 0: x=0 y=0 w=1600 h=900
[gs_window_move_resize_window] gs-window-x11.c:243 (00:08:37):   Move and/or resize window on monitor 0: x=0 y=0 w=1600 h=900
[gs_manager_timed_switch] gs-manager.c:445 (00:08:37):   Start switch to greeter timer
[gs_window_xevent] gs-window-x11.c:369 (00:08:37):   not raising our windows
[window_map_event_cb] gs-manager.c:233 (00:08:37):   Handling window map_event event
[gs_listener_resume_suspend] gs-listener-dbus.c:513 (00:08:37):  Resume suspend: fd=14
[manager_maybe_grab_window] gs-manager.c:204 (00:08:37):     Moving grab to 0x5595f8d5a290
[gs_grab_move_keyboard] gs-grab-x11.c:450 (00:08:37):    Moving keyboard grab from E3 to 3A0000C
[gs_grab_move_keyboard] gs-grab-x11.c:457 (00:08:37):    *** doing X server grab
[gs_grab_release_keyboard] gs-grab-x11.c:279 (00:08:37):     Ungrabbing keyboard
[gs_grab_get_keyboard] gs-grab-x11.c:153 (00:08:37):     Grabbing keyboard widget=3A0000C
[gs_grab_move_keyboard] gs-grab-x11.c:479 (00:08:37):    *** releasing X server grab
[gs_grab_move_mouse] gs-grab-x11.c:395 (00:08:37):   Moving pointer grab from E3 to 3A0000C
[gs_grab_move_mouse] gs-grab-x11.c:402 (00:08:37):   *** doing X server grab
[gs_grab_release_mouse] gs-grab-x11.c:320 (00:08:37):    Ungrabbing pointer
[gs_grab_get_mouse] gs-grab-x11.c:213 (00:08:37):    Grabbing mouse widget=3A0000C
[gs_grab_move_mouse] gs-grab-x11.c:425 (00:08:37):   *** releasing X server grab
[listener_dbus_handle_system_message] gs-listener-dbus.c:1330 (00:08:37):    obj_path=/org/freedesktop/login1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties method=PropertiesChanged destination=(null)
[update_geometry] gs-window-x11.c:197 (00:08:37):    got geometry for monitor 0: x=0 y=0 w=1600 h=900
[update_geometry] gs-window-x11.c:210 (00:08:37):    using geometry for monitor 0: x=0 y=0 w=1600 h=900
[gs_window_move_resize_window] gs-window-x11.c:243 (00:08:37):   Move and/or resize window on monitor 0: x=0 y=0 w=1600 h=900
[update_geometry] gs-window-x11.c:197 (00:08:37):    got geometry for monitor 0: x=0 y=0 w=1600 h=900
[update_geometry] gs-window-x11.c:210 (00:08:37):    using geometry for monitor 0: x=0 y=0 w=1600 h=900
[gs_window_move_resize_window] gs-window-x11.c:243 (00:08:37):   Move and/or resize window on monitor 0: x=0 y=0 w=1600 h=900
[gs_listener_send_lock_session] gs-listener-dbus.c:180 (00:08:38):   Send lock session
[listener_dbus_handle_system_message] gs-listener-dbus.c:1330 (00:08:38):    obj_path=(null) interface=(null) method=(null) destination=:1.316
[listener_dbus_handle_system_message] gs-listener-dbus.c:1330 (00:08:39):    obj_path=/org/freedesktop/login1/session/c5 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties method=PropertiesChanged destination=(null)
[listener_dbus_handle_system_message] gs-listener-dbus.c:1330 (00:08:39):    obj_path=/org/freedesktop/login1/session/c12 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties method=PropertiesChanged destination=(null)
[listener_dbus_handle_system_message] gs-listener-dbus.c:1330 (00:08:39):    obj_path=/org/freedesktop/login1/seat/seat0 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties method=PropertiesChanged destination=(null)
process 23463: arguments to dbus_message_new_method_call() were incorrect, assertion "path != NULL" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-message.c line 1340.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
[query_session_active] gs-listener-dbus.c:1124 (00:08:39):   Couldn't allocate the dbus message
[listener_dbus_handle_system_message] gs-listener-dbus.c:1361 (00:08:39):    systemd notified ActiveSession 0
[listener_session_switched_cb] gs-monitor.c:298 (00:08:39):  Session switched: 0
[gs_manager_stop_switch] gs-manager.c:456 (00:08:39):    Stop switch to greeter timer
[listener_dbus_handle_system_message] gs-listener-dbus.c:1330 (00:08:39):    obj_path=/org/freedesktop/login1/seat/seat0 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties method=PropertiesChanged destination=(null)
[listener_dbus_handle_system_message] gs-listener-dbus.c:1330 (00:08:39):    obj_path=/org/freedesktop/login1/session/c12 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties method=PropertiesChanged destination=(null)
[listener_dbus_handle_system_message] gs-listener-dbus.c:1330 (00:08:39):    obj_path=/org/freedesktop/login1/user/_108 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties method=PropertiesChanged destination=(null)
[listener_dbus_handle_system_message] gs-listener-dbus.c:1330 (00:08:39):    obj_path=/org/freedesktop/login1/seat/seat0 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties method=PropertiesChanged destination=(null)
process 23463: arguments to dbus_message_new_method_call() were incorrect, assertion "path != NULL" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-message.c line 1340.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
[query_session_active] gs-listener-dbus.c:1124 (00:08:39):   Couldn't allocate the dbus message
[listener_dbus_handle_system_message] gs-listener-dbus.c:1361 (00:08:39):    systemd notified ActiveSession 0
[listener_session_switched_cb] gs-monitor.c:298 (00:08:39):  Session switched: 0
[listener_dbus_handle_system_message] gs-listener-dbus.c:1330 (00:08:39):    obj_path=/org/freedesktop/login1/session/c5 interface=org.freedesktop.login1.Session method=Lock destination=(null)
### 10 seconds have passed - entering password now
[listener_dbus_handle_system_message] gs-listener-dbus.c:1330 (00:08:51):    obj_path=/org/freedesktop/login1/session/c5 interface=org.freedesktop.login1.Session method=Unlock destination=(null)
[listener_dbus_handle_system_message] gs-listener-dbus.c:1330 (00:08:51):    obj_path=/org/freedesktop/login1/session/c13 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties method=PropertiesChanged destination=(null)
[listener_dbus_handle_system_message] gs-listener-dbus.c:1330 (00:08:51):    obj_path=/org/freedesktop/login1/session/c5 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties method=PropertiesChanged destination=(null)
[listener_dbus_handle_system_message] gs-listener-dbus.c:1330 (00:08:51):    obj_path=/org/freedesktop/login1/seat/seat0 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties method=PropertiesChanged destination=(null)
process 23463: arguments to dbus_message_new_method_call() were incorrect, assertion "path != NULL" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-message.c line 1340.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
[query_session_active] gs-listener-dbus.c:1124 (00:08:51):   Couldn't allocate the dbus message
[listener_dbus_handle_system_message] gs-listener-dbus.c:1361 (00:08:51):    systemd notified ActiveSession 0
[listener_session_switched_cb] gs-monitor.c:298 (00:08:51):  Session switched: 0
[xroot_filter] gs-listener-x11.c:124 (00:08:52):     ScreenSaver stopped
### 10 more seconds have passwd - Killing
### Killed now
```

Diffing this to a known-good system yields:

```
$ comm -3 <(grep -iv grab good | sed 's/[0-9:]\+/[NN]/g;s/[ \t]\+/ /g' | sort) <(grep -iv grab bad | sed 's/[0-9:]\+/[NN]/g;s/[ \t]\+/ /g' | sort) | head -n2
[init_session_id] gs-listener-dbus.c[NN] ([NN])[NN] Got session-id[NN] (null)
[init_session_id] gs-listener-dbus.c[NN] ([NN])[NN] Got session-id[NN] /org/freedesktop/login[NN]/session/c[NN]
```

And indeed, something appears to be very awkward about session setup:

```
$ loginctl session-status
Could not get properties: No such process
```

Comment: Hah!  You'll find that the only solution is mine and that is to [use xscreensaver and delete light-locker](https://askubuntu.com/a/602184/344926)

Comment: Have you by any chance attempted to launch `light-locker` utilizing the debug option mentioned in the man page? http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/light-locker.1.html

Comment: @anx your bounty will be lost in 5 hours...  want me to write a repeat of [my original answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/602184/344926)?  It's not what you want, but I had the same problem at the time, lost many hours and just went to xscreensaver (and had fun with it)

Comment: well, you've got 15 of your bounty already back!  Your answer is better than mine, so is your question, so upvoted both!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR: light-locker keeps the screen black if systemd cannot read /proc**

- `light-locker` depends on `dbus` providing `IPC`.
- `dbus` depends on `systemd-logind` providing `session` information.
- `systemd-logind` depends on `/proc` providing `process` information.

**Meaning this will not work very well together:**

```
$ file /sbin/init
/sbin/init: symbolic link to /lib/systemd/systemd
$ mount | grep proc
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hidepid=2,gid=1337)
```

**And neither can be expected to:**

> hidepid isn't really compatible with systemd. sorry. [..] Anyway, closing as this was not caused by systemd. -- [Lennart Poettering](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2941#issuecomment-213931080)

**Partial Solution 1**

*Partial* solution, because it comes with information disclosure.

Allow unprivileged programs (such as systemd, after dropping privileges) to access other users process info in `/proc`.

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,hidepid=0 /proc
 # and fix /etc/fstab accordingly
```

**Partial Solution 2**

*Partial* solution, because systemd might break in other places, not just logind.

Add systemd-logind to the appropriate group, most conveniently achieved by adding a service Drop-In.

```
$ addgroup showpid
$ adduser myuser showpid
$ sudo mount -o remount,hidepid=2,gid=showpid /proc
 # and fix /etc/fstab accordingly
$ echo -e '[Service]\nSupplementaryGroups=showpid' | sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/systemd-logind.service.d/10-showpid.conf
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind
```

After **either** solution, the `Got session-id: (null)` message should look more like `Got session-id: /org/freedesktop/login1/c7` and light-locker will be able to communicate properly via `dbus`.

---

**What should i have done do figure this out way faster?**

- If something changed, and you cannot quickly figure out what changed, just grab the backup already and `diff -ruiN` the whole system.
- Document the first time an issue occured more precisely, so sorting logfiles/IDS reports by time will quickly reveal the relevant cause.
- File more bug reports. Applications silently failing under conditions that will later cause headache and/or system lockup is unacceptable.

Comment: So did you file some bug report(s) about this?