# Ubuntu lockscreen password box stuck in RTL mode and password doesn't work

Tags: gnome, login, password, keyboard-layout

When I lock my ubuntu laptop with a right-to-left (RTL) language is selected, the password box in the lockscreen is right-to-left and my password doesn't work. Probably because there is an invisible character for RTL that I cannot get rid of.

I can change the language by clicking the button beside the password box, but that doesn't change RTL-ness of the box. The only way to log back in is to kill gnome-shell which makes me lose all my work. UNACCEPTABLE!

[image]

I'm using ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS with lightdm and Gnome desktop. For now I have uninstalled gnome-screensaver which seems to do the trick. But Super+L no longer works to lock the screen. I can live with that. Found this workaround here: [Change language layout in screen lock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599470/change-language-layout-in-screen-lock).

Any idea if there is a way to change the RTL-ness of the password box in the lock screen? Note that in 18.04.2 LTS the lock screen seems to be different than the login screen.

Comment: so the password and the password box are in RTL mode but sometimes an extra LTR character gets thrown in there? or is it RTL? why can't you get rid of it? that's weird, do arrow keys word to move arround the password? do the backspace and delete keys both work also?

Comment: @tatsu the password box's text direction seems to match the language that is **selected** when you lock the screen. If it is a RTL language, it is impossible to switch it back to LTR to enter the english password. The button supposedly changes the language, but not the RTL flag.

Comment: and why not change the password to a RTL password?

Comment: @HosseinShah: Which button are you talking about? IIRC, there is no button by default on lightdm-gtk-greeter to change input source (but LightDM can be configured to show it). Are you possibly mixing it up with the button for switching display language? The display language is unrelated to this problem, of course.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I have included the screenshot in my post. I believe it was the gnome-desktop screen lock. I disabled auto lock since and am living happily so far.

Comment: @tatsu because possibly the reverse problem would happen with an RTL password, plus a lot more since ascii english has the best support in general. I wouldn't even want to go down the path of trying a unicoded password.

Comment: i don't understand. the way I see it it's much easier for you to be able to type that in all sistuations than vice versa. anyways there's no miracle solution here.